# Why directives method is available from parent scope

Tags: angularjs

*AngularJS v1.2.28*

Here is my sidebar controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('SidebarController', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {

        $scope.isItemActive = function (section) {
            return ($location.path() === section);
        };
    }
]);
```

And sidebar's template:

```
<section  data-ng-controller="SidebarController">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.new-subscription"
           ui-route="/dashboard/subscription/new"
           class="item "
           ng-class="{active: isItemActive('/dashboard/subscription/new')}"> 
            + New Subscription
        </a>

        <subscriptions-list></subscriptions-list>
</section>
```

Subscription list's directive:

```
angular.module('core').directive('subscriptionsList', ['Subscription', '$state', '$location',
    function(Subscription, $state, $location) {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/subscriptions-list.client.view.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                ....

                scope.isItemActive = function(path, subscription) {
                    var curPath = path + '/' + subscription._id;
                    return ($location.path() === curPath);
                };
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

As you can see, both controller and directive have function isItemActive.
For some reason, when I call isItemActive('/dashboard/subscription/new') in sidebars template, I got error "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined" because it calls isItemActive() from subscriptionsList directive instead controllers directive.

How is that possible? How method from a directive can be accessible outside of directive's scope? I haven't used binding for this method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive doesn't use an isolated scope and doesn't create a child scope. The scope you use to declare `isItemActive` inside your directive is actually the scope the directive is used in, which is the same as the controller's scope. You basically override your controller's `isItemActive`.

You need to either use an isolated scope using `scope: {}` or create a child scope using `scope: true`.

You can read more about the differences here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes